# Focus is not trigger on details focus

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

The problem is to style the detail html element when the [focus pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) is trigger.

> The `:focus` CSS pseudo-class represents an element (such as a form input) that has received focus. It is generally triggered when the user clicks or taps on an element or selects it with the keyboard's <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus)

Here is a demo snippet:

```css
:focus { outline: none; }

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 2em;
}

details {
  background: red;
}

summary {
  background: green;
}

details:hover {
  box-shadow:0 0 0 2px blue;
}

/* this one doesn not work */
details:focus {
  box-shadow:0 0 0 2px blue;
}

button:focus {
  box-shadow:0 0 0 2px blue;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="press tab to switch focus">

<details>
  <summary>summary should be blue on focus</summary>
  
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi, ex facilis iusto. Ab laboriosam deserunt neque fuga reprehenderit, inventore non? Quo sint iusto commodi architecto magni sit maiores beatae exercitationem.
  </p>
</details>

<button>the button should be blue on focus</button>
```

[Try it online!](https://jsfiddle.net/yt3ogc10/)

Answer (score 1):

Focus does just work out of the box with interactive elements (e.g. inputs, buttons, links,..).

If you want to make another element focusable, you can add the tabindex attribute.

In your case it would look like that:

```
<input type="text" value="press tab to switch focus">

<details tabindex="0">
  <summary>summary should be blue on focus</summary>

   <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi, ex 
      facilis iusto. Ab laboriosam deserunt neque fuga reprehenderit, 
      inventore non? Quo sint iusto commodi architecto magni sit maiores 
      beatae exercitationem.
   </p>
</details>

<button>the button should be blue on focus</button>
```

Comment: Well your answer helped me a lot to find the actual solution. Have an upvote for solving the question in the title.

Answer (score 0):

After playing a bit with `tabIndex` as suggested by Sebsemillia, I went for another solution. In the origianl snippet we have this structure:

```
 - input
 - details
   - summary
 - button
```

Without `tabIndex=0`, the browser focus on `input`, then skip `details` because it is not an interactive element, then move on to summary, then reach `button`.

With `tabIndex=0`, the browser focus on `input`, then is forced to `details` even it is not an interactive element, then move on to summary, then reach `button`.

Now here is the real problem with my question. Why bother give focus to details? Well the question's title is not good because what OP wants is to wrap the whole `details/summary` with a blue border.

here how to actually fix the code.

Replace

```css
details:focus {
  box-shadow:0 0 0 2px blue;
}
```

with

```css
details:focus-within {
  box-shadow:0 0 0 2px blue;
}
```

> The `:focus-within` CSS pseudo-class matches an element if the element or any of its descendants are focused. In other words, it represents an element that is itself matched by the `:focus` pseudo-class or has a descendant that is matched by `:focus`. (This includes descendants in shadow trees.)

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within)

```css
:focus { outline: none; }

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 2em;
}

details {
  background: red;
}

summary {
  background: green;
}

details:hover {
  box-shadow:0 0 0 2px blue;
}

/* this should work */
details:focus-within {
  box-shadow:0 0 0 2px blue;
}

button:focus {
  box-shadow:0 0 0 2px blue;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="press tab to switch focus">

<details>
  <summary>summary should be blue on focus</summary>
  
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi, ex facilis iusto. Ab laboriosam deserunt neque fuga reprehenderit, inventore non? Quo sint iusto commodi architecto magni sit maiores beatae exercitationem.
  </p>
</details>

<button>the button should be blue on focus</button>
```